# How to make an array of objects of undefined length of a class with parameterized constructor in JAVA?

Tags: java, generics

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number.");
int n=sc.nextInt();
PIDManager[] ob;
for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
{   
    ob[j]=new PIDManager("Thread Number "+(j+1));
}
```

Here `PIDManager` is a class, and the compiler shows an error that `ob` may not have been defined.

Comment: I got that, but the class PIDManager has a parameterized constructor, and I need to send different String to each object of the object array.

Comment: you need `PIDManager[] ob = new PIDManager[n];` This is constructing the array with the given length (this is needed in addition to constructing the members).

Answer (score 3):

Use growable array like ArrayList if you dont know the size in advance like:

```
List<PIDManager> ob = new ArrayList<>();
..
ob.add(new PIDManager("Thread Number "+(j+1)));
```

and then add the elements to it with add method. If you know the size then you could define the array like:

```
PIDManager[] ob = new PIDManager[n];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the size of an array in Java when you initialize it (arrays do not **grow** in Java). Use a collection like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` instead.

Also, you haven't initialized your array at all.

```
PIDManager[] ob;
```

Should be (assuming you did know the size at the time).

```
PIDManager[] ob = new PIDManager[size];
```

There seems to be something wrong with the logic in the snippet though. Since you seem to actually need an array of size `n` judging from `for (int j=0;j<n;j++)`